# Dropdown list not getting binded

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a Dropdown List in the asp page which I bind it in codebehind.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="authorList" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

In C#,

```
  PublishingCompanyEntities p = new PublishingCompanyEntities();
        var a = (from s in p.Authors
                 select s.FirstName);
        authorList.DataSource = p.Authors;
        authorList.DataTextField = "Firstname";
        authorList.DataValueField = "FirstName";
```

where PublishingCompanyEntities is an entity class got using ADO.NET Entity model. However, the dropdownlist is not getting binded. Can u let me know the mistake I've been making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling the [`.DataBind()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5e5992d.aspx) method on the drop down after assigning the `DataSource` property:

```
authorList.DataBind();
```

Contrary to WinForms, in ASP.NET you need to invoke this method explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a call to `authorList.DataBind();`